How can I construct this large graph with graph_tool faster?
Im trying to re-implement the 3d seam carving from this paper in python: https://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/papers/vidret.pdf
Specifically I have a 3d array called mask_data that masks out areas of the 3d volume I want to be prioritized, aka not removed. For testing I just use an array of 0's with a 20% chance any of the places become a 1. The paper shows how to theoretically construct a graph that will allow the min cut to be a decent seam to remove, and the following function does that. The issue is that even with a 128^3 graph it takes 13 minutes to construct the graph on my M2 max macbook. I tried parallelising the operation but I only succeeded in making it take longer.
Any ideas/implementations that would allow for faster creation of the graph structure? I am using the graph_tool library that implements its functions in C++ and calculates the max flow min cut quickly in the next step so id like to continue using it.
import graph_tool.all as gt
def create_directed_energy_graph_from_mask(mask_data, direction='left', large_weight=1e8):
    z,y,x = mask_data.shape  # Dimensions of the 3D mask array
    g = gt.Graph(directed=True)
    weight_prop = g.new_edge_property("int")  # Edge property for weights

    # Function to get linear index from 3D coordinates, assuming C-style row-major order
    index = lambda i, j, k: i * y * x + j * x + k

    # Add vertices
    num_vertices = z * y * x
    g.add_vertex(num_vertices)
    vertices = list(g.vertices())  # Get the list of vertices

    # Define neighbor offsets based on directionality
    # Source to sink propagation direction - positive axes directions
    directions = {
        'left': [(0, 0, 1)],  # propagate right
        'right': [(0, 0, -1)],  # propagate left
        'top': [(0, 1, 0)],  # propagate downwards
        'bottom': [(0, -1, 0)],  # propagate upwards
        'front': [(1, 0, 0)],  # propagate back
        'back': [(-1, 0, 0)]  # propagate front
    }

    neighbors = directions[direction]
    print(x,y,z)
    
    for i in range(z):
        for j in range(y):
            for k in range(x):
                current_index = index(i, j, k)
                # print(current_index, len(vertices))
                current_vertex = vertices[current_index]

                # Check each neighbor direction for valid connections
                for di, dj, dk in neighbors:
                    ni, nj, nk = i + di, j + dj, k + dk
                    if 0 <= ni < z and 0 <= nj < y and 0 <= nk < x:
                        neighbor_index = index(ni, nj, nk)
                        neighbor_vertex = vertices[neighbor_index]

                        # print(current_index, neighbor_index)

                        # Determine edge weight
                        weight = 10 if mask_data[ni, nj, nk] != 0 or mask_data[i, j, k] != 0 else 1

                        # Add edge and assign weight
                        e = g.add_edge(current_vertex, neighbor_vertex) #forward edge with energy value
                        e2 = g.add_edge(neighbor_vertex, current_vertex) #backward edge with large energy value
                        weight_prop[e] = weight
                        weight_prop[e2] = large_weight

                # Add each diagonal backwards neighbor inf edge, ie x-1, y-1 and x-1, y+1 for YX plane
                if k > 0 and j > 0:
                    neighbor_index = index(i, j-1, k-1)
                    neighbor_vertex = vertices[neighbor_index]
                    # print(current_index, neighbor_index)
                    # print(i,j,k, " y-1, x-1 ", i, j-1, k-1) 
                    e = g.add_edge(current_vertex, neighbor_vertex)
                    weight_prop[e] = large_weight+1
                if k > 0 and j < y-1:
                    neighbor_index = index(i, j+1, k-1)
                    neighbor_vertex = vertices[neighbor_index]
                    # print(current_index, neighbor_index)
                    # print(i,j,k, "  y+1 x-1 ", i, j+1, k-1)
                    e = g.add_edge(current_vertex, neighbor_vertex)
                    weight_prop[e] = large_weight+1

                # print(i,j,k, current_index)
                    
                # Add each diagonal backwards neighbor inf edge for ik plane
                if k > 0 and i > 0:
                    neighbor_index = index(i-1, j, k-1)
                    neighbor_vertex = vertices[neighbor_index]
                    # print(current_index, neighbor_index)
                    e = g.add_edge(current_vertex, neighbor_vertex)
                    weight_prop[e] = large_weight+2
                if k > 0 and i < z-1:
                    neighbor_index = index(i+1, j, k-1)
                    neighbor_vertex = vertices[neighbor_index]
                    # print(current_index, neighbor_index)
                    e = g.add_edge(current_vertex, neighbor_vertex)
                    weight_prop[e] = large_weight+2

    g.edge_properties["weight"] = weight_prop
    return g, weight_prop

The paper does mention multi-resolution banding as a speed up, but all the other parts of the pipeline run quickly, its just creating the graph that is slow. I may have to figure out what they mean by that though if I cant optimise this code. Also note that this version only works for the 'left' direction as of now.
I tried parallelising the code by splitting the mask data array and computing subgraphs, expected it to run faster, but it ran slower, perhaps due to the graph recombination operation being expensive.

Can you run python's profiler on this and edit the question with those results? That would go a long way in getting help with this problem, as it's currently difficult to tell where the issues are, and we don't have mask_data so we can't run this ourselves to test.
That library's documentation notes that batch adds are much faster given some conditions, here is an example for add_edge_list that may be worth a try as a first pass at the problem:
https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.Graph.html#graph_tool.Graph.add_edge_list

Thanks for the tip, I refactored the code to add the edges all at once and it definitely helped quite a bit. I also implemented the multi-resolution banding also which allowed for a much smaller graph to be constructed

Based on your answer looks like you got a pretty good solution out of it, good work mate.

This code using the add_edge_list instead of adding edges & vertices individually is a good improvement. It also adds source and sink nodes to the left and right faces efficiently, and allows for multi resolution banding to mask out irrelevant parts of the volume with -1 values, which is implemented in a different part of the code. All these changes made the runtime go from 15 minutes to 20 seconds on a 256^3 volume.
def create_masked_directed_energy_graph_from_mask(mask_data, direction='left', large_weight=1e8):
    z, y, x = mask_data.shape  # Dimensions of the 3D mask array
    # print(z, y, x)
    g = gt.Graph(directed=True)
    weight_prop = g.new_edge_property("int")  # Edge property for weights

    # Create vertex properties for i, j, k positions
    x_prop = g.new_vertex_property("int")
    y_prop = g.new_vertex_property("int")
    z_prop = g.new_vertex_property("int")

    # Create a mapping from mask coordinates to vertex indices
    coord_to_vertex = {}

    # Add vertices only for the non-zero elements in the mask
    # stime = time.time()
    # Find indices of non -1 elements using numpy vectorization
    non_neg_indices = np.argwhere(mask_data != -1)

    # Add all vertices at once
    g.add_vertex(len(non_neg_indices))

    # Create a mapping from mask coordinates to vertex indices
    coord_to_vertex = {}
    
    # Assign vertices to coordinates and set properties
    for idx, (i, j, k) in enumerate(non_neg_indices):
        v = g.vertex(idx)
        coord_to_vertex[(i, j, k)] = v
        x_prop[v] = k
        y_prop[v] = j
        z_prop[v] = i
    # print("Time taken to add vertices to coord_to_vertex:", time.time()-stime)

    # Define neighbor offsets based on directionality
    directions = {
        'left': [(0, 0, 1)],  # propagate right
        'right': [(0, 0, -1)],  # propagate left
        'top': [(0, 1, 0)],  # propagate downwards
        'bottom': [(0, -1, 0)],  # propagate upwards
        'front': [(1, 0, 0)],  # propagate back
        'back': [(-1, 0, 0)]  # propagate front
    }

    neighbors = directions[direction]
    
    edges = []
    weights = []

    # stime = time.time()

    for (i, j, k), current_vertex in coord_to_vertex.items():
        # Check each neighbor direction for valid connections
        for di, dj, dk in neighbors:
            ni, nj, nk = i + di, j + dj, k + dk
            if (ni, nj, nk) in coord_to_vertex:
                neighbor_vertex = coord_to_vertex[(ni, nj, nk)]
                # Determine edge weight
                weight = 10 if mask_data[ni, nj, nk] != 0 or mask_data[i, j, k] != 0 else 1
                # Add edge and assign weight
                edges.append((int(current_vertex), int(neighbor_vertex)))  # forward edge with energy value
                weights.append(weight)
                edges.append((int(neighbor_vertex), int(current_vertex)))  # backward edge with large energy value
                weights.append(int(large_weight))

        # Add each diagonal backwards neighbor inf edge, i.e., x-1, y-1 and x-1, y+1 for YX plane
        if (i, j-1, k-1) in coord_to_vertex:
            neighbor_vertex = coord_to_vertex[(i, j-1, k-1)]
            edges.append((int(current_vertex), int(neighbor_vertex)))
            weights.append(int(large_weight) + 1)
        if (i, j+1, k-1) in coord_to_vertex:
            neighbor_vertex = coord_to_vertex[(i, j+1, k-1)]
            edges.append((int(current_vertex), int(neighbor_vertex)))
            weights.append(int(large_weight) + 1)

        # Add each diagonal backwards neighbor inf edge for IK plane
        if (i-1, j, k-1) in coord_to_vertex:
            neighbor_vertex = coord_to_vertex[(i-1, j, k-1)]
            edges.append((int(current_vertex), int(neighbor_vertex)))
            weights.append(int(large_weight) + 1)
        if (i+1, j, k-1) in coord_to_vertex:
            neighbor_vertex = coord_to_vertex[(i+1, j, k-1)]
            edges.append((int(current_vertex), int(neighbor_vertex)))
            weights.append(int(large_weight) + 1)

    # Convert edges and weights to numpy arrays
    edges = np.array(edges, dtype=np.int32)
    weights = np.array(weights, dtype=np.int32)

    # Add edges to the graph using add_edge_list
    g.add_edge_list(edges)
    weight_prop.a = weights

    # print("Time taken to add edges to graph:", time.time()-stime)
    # stime = time.time()
    # Add source and sink nodes
    source = g.add_vertex()
    sink = g.add_vertex()

    # Helper function to get vertex indices for a face
    def get_face_vertices(face, coord_to_vertex, z, y, x):
        indices = []
        if face == 'left':
            for j in range(y):
                for k in range(x):
                    for i in range(z):
                        if (i, j, k) in coord_to_vertex:
                            indices.append(coord_to_vertex[(i, j, k)])
                            break
        elif face == 'right':
            for j in range(y):
                for k in range(x):
                    for i in range (z):
                        if (z-i, j, k) in coord_to_vertex:
                            indices.append(coord_to_vertex[(z-i, j, k)])
                            break
        elif face == 'top':
            for i in range(z):
                for k in range(x):
                    for j in range(y):
                        if (i, j, k) in coord_to_vertex:
                            indices.append(coord_to_vertex[(i, j, k)])
                            break
        elif face == 'bottom':
            for i in range(z):
                for k in range(x):
                    for j in range(y):
                        if (i, y-j, k) in coord_to_vertex:
                            indices.append(coord_to_vertex[(i, y-j, k)])
                            break
        elif face == 'front':
            for i in range(z):
                for j in range(y):
                    for k in range(x):
                        if (i, j, k) in coord_to_vertex:
                            indices.append(coord_to_vertex[(i, j, k)])
                            break
        elif face == 'back':
            for i in range(z):
                for j in range(y):
                    for k in range(x):
                        if (i, j, x-k) in coord_to_vertex:
                            indices.append(coord_to_vertex[(i, j, x-k)])
                            break
        return indices

    # Connect source to 'front' face
    front_vertices = get_face_vertices('front', coord_to_vertex, z, y, x)
    for v in front_vertices:
        e = g.add_edge(source, v)
        weight_prop[e] = large_weight

    # Connect sink to 'back' face
    back_vertices = get_face_vertices('back', coord_to_vertex, z, y, x)
    for v in back_vertices:
        e = g.add_edge(v, sink)
        weight_prop[e] = large_weight

    g.edge_properties["weight"] = weight_prop
    # print("Time taken to add source and sink nodes:", time.time()-stime)
    return g, source, sink, weight_prop, x_prop, y_prop, z_prop
    ```
 

